# Given a YEAR, how to get the start of the year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the year I want in a variable

```
DECLARE @CURRENT_YEAR AS INT
SET @CURRENT_YEAR = 2016
```

Now I want to beginning of the year for the year @Current_Year

How can I do this without parsing a date that I build using a varchar?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) function

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS (@CURRENT_YEAR, 1, 1)
```

Comment: My sqlserver doesn't support that.

Comment: @coolbreeze Why don't you want to use `select cast('20160101' as datetime)`?

Comment: That's a new feature in SQL Server **2012** not available in earlier versions

Comment: @JakubLortz because I don't want to parse a string if there is a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

This will get the first date of the current year.

```
select dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

--EDIT--

Since you are obviously on a version earlier than 2012 when DATEFROMPARTS was introduced you could use a little math.

```
DECLARE @CURRENT_YEAR AS INT 
SET @CURRENT_YEAR = 2016

select DATEADD(year, @Current_Year - 1900, 0)
```

Comment: can you explain this, I noticed dateadd and datediff used allot.

Comment: I don't want to use getDATE(), I have the year in my INT varaible @current_year

Comment: I apologize. I missed the int variable detail. The answer from Jakub is better for your situation.